# Is it OK when users receive rep for the edit and not for the their original answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

Well, I've done many edits in SO and have never received anything in return, which is just fine and I get it that SO's principle is to share. But I have always been skeptical about this specially when I see users have earned thousands for simple JavaScript solutions which are written in the first 10 pages of any manual.

But today I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15553059/revisions) in which the user has actually provided poor, and even wrong information, at first but over time with the help of edits, the answer is now a very good one which is getting up-votes, but the reputation is being referred to the author and not the editors, which seems to me there is a problem here and it should not be like that.

- This particular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15553059/revisions) is just an example and I'm asking in general if it's a good Idea that reputation is not being shared over with editors?
- I know we're not supposed to accept edits which do a dramatic change to an answer but what if a high rep user did that? Should we flag it? How does SO handle it?
- What if a question got improved overtime with small edits in a way that the original version is not there anymore. Is't then up-voting that answer means we're up-voting the edits and not the original one?

Comment: Reputation is only a very, very rough measure of ability (if even that.) There's always going to be unjustified rep gains for less-than-good content, and people writing genius content earning little rep. That said, it's of course not wrong to think about how to make it fairer. Rewarding edits with rep has been considered several times - but it is much, much more complex than it may seem. It's not a trivial thing to do well - and may be not possible to do at all.

Comment: The edits to your example post are almost purely formatting.  There actual content of the post is almost entirely the authors.  There's not even much of any re-wording, it's virtually all just formatting.  Someone who's never even heard of SQL could do pretty much all of that editing.

Comment: @Servy, yeah that was just an example, but if you look closer the author didn't said the limits right which makes the answer kinda invalid but I'm sure we can find better examples illustrating my intention here

Comment: @Pekka웃, yeah got it thanks. I didn't mean to suggest giving rep to edits but just to discuss about it and learn how to look at the reputation system. `Reputation is only a very, very rough measure of ability (if even that)` just makes it so clear to me, that's like my answer here

Comment: Well so far you've only ever showed examples of cases that disprove your point, so if you want your point to hold weight, you should be providing examples that *support* your point.

Comment: Also this question is from 2009, today it would probably get massively downvoted and closed

Comment: i don't necessarily think it's... right, or fair, but... the user didn't do it on purpose, it just happened as the community came by and improved the information. No action/change needed. This is the process working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm asking in general if it's a good Idea that reputation is not being shared over with editors?

Yes. Otherwise, people would start editing like crazy, *especially* the good, highly upvoted answers that don't need any editing at all. People do anything to gain rep. We already have enough minor edits by people who hope for the tiny amount of 2 points.

Also, as you know, edits shouldn't be too drastic. They shouldn't change the *message* of an answer, only improve the quality of how it is conveyed. So normally, after a revision the answer still reflects what the owner intended to say and they deserve the rep.

> but what if a high rep user did that? [drastically edit an answer]

There are no special rules for high-rep users. However, if you see this happen, first carefully evaluate if really something bad happened. In most cases you'll conclude it's OK and move on. If not, the best thing to do is probably to ping the editor. Don't start an edit war.

> What if a question got improved overtime with small edits [...]

As long as a post is not a [community wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/168269) the OP will get the rep. I think it's fair. Look at it this way: apparently, the OP started something that was worth the ongoing attention of the community. That's an important achievement in itself.

Answer (score -9):

Well, isn't this why Community Wiki exists? Answers that got substantially better thanks to multiple users' edits should be flagged for moderator attention so that they can be CW.

Comment: If someone wants to allow others to edit the substance of their post, they can mark it as CW.  You editing the substance of someone else's post when it's not CW doesn't mean it should become CW, it means your edit should be rolled back.

Comment: CW doesn't *share* rep, it just takes it away from everyone.